# Is it possible to cast database columns to different types in the L2S entity?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Given a table or view with an Integer column is it possible to do a conversion or cast to a String value in the DBML or create a calculated property on the entity that can be used as a relationship to another entity?

[image]

I have tried making the generated type a string but it gives an error:
Error   1   DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'Int' and Type 'System.String' in Column 'Foo' of Type 'FooRecord' is not supported.       0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything like this - not in the Linq-to-SQL data model, for sure. If it's an `INT` in the database, it's an `INT` in the model and cannot be "manipulated" into being a string all of a sudden...

But what you *could* do is extend that class that Linq-to-SQL generates for you - it's a **partial** class, e.g. you can extend it in a separate, second file:

**YourEntityEx.cs**

```
public partial class YourEntity
{
   public string YourPropertyAsString
   {
      get { return YourProperty.ToString(); }
      set { YourProperty = Convert.ToInt32(value); }  // if you even this
   }
}
```

This way, you now have a second property `YourPropertyAsString` on your `YourEntity` class that will always be exactly the same as `YourProperty` - only of type `string`.

Comment: Can this be used in a relationship then? If not it sounds like my only real option is to change the database source, i.e. cast it in a view.